# ggplot2: How to match Standard Error and Value in accord with a Third Column

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this table (below), which I've converted wide-to-long from which I want to plot the "logFPKM" for each "sample" grouped by "gene_id" using ggplot2(geom_bar). Also, I'd like to match the standard error ("se") accordingly to each sample-logFPKM. Here's the head of my table:

---

```
gene_id        sample logFPKM            se
PCBA_RS20130   CW     2.82138999505533   0.0510157917418624
PCBA_RS20130   CW     2.82138999505533   0.0614430466292
PCBA_RS20130   CW     2.82138999505533   0.15767922584651
PCBA_RS20130   W24    3.30091961220465   0.0510157917418624
PCBA_RS20130   W24    3.30091961220465   0.0614430466292
PCBA_RS20130   W24    3.30091961220465   0.15767922584651
PCBA_RS20130   W72    3.03503118006935   0.0510157917418624
PCBA_RS20130   W72    3.03503118006935   0.0614430466292
PCBA_RS20130   W72    3.03503118006935   0.15767922584651
PCBA_RS20135   CW     6.9229217846409    0.00450698521094983
PCBA_RS20135   CW     6.9229217846409    0.0224906710108503
PCBA_RS20135   CW     6.9229217846409    0.0917704536947984
PCBA_RS20135   W24    6.84058248620209   0.00450698521094983
PCBA_RS20135   W24    6.84058248620209   0.0224906710108503
PCBA_RS20135   W24    6.84058248620209   0.091770453694798
PCBA_RS20135   W72    5.95705243892052   0.00450698521094983
PCBA_RS20135   W72    5.95705243892052   0.0224906710108503
PCBA_RS20135   W72    5.95705243892052   0.0917704536947984
```

---

The code as it is now (below), successfully grabs the logFPKM (y) value for each class (CW,W24,W72) in the sample (x) column. However, the "se" values are being plotted three times for each logFPKM bar. And I'm struggling while trying to make both "logFPKM" and "se" 'walk together' with the sample classes. How can I associate the "se" values for each "sample" class (CW,W24,W72) correctly to each logFPKM?

```
ggplot(both_long, aes(x=sample,y=logFPKM,fill=factor(gene_id), ymax=logFPKM+se, ymin=logFPKM-se)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(position = "dodge")
```

---

Here's how the ggplot2 output looks like:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHble.png)

and here's the dput:

```
dput(both_long)
```

> structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
> 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("PCBA_RS20130", 
> "PCBA_RS20135"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
> 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
> ), .Label = c("CW", "W24", "W72"), class = "factor"), V3 = c(2.82138999505533, 
> 2.82138999505533, 2.82138999505533, 3.30091961220465, 3.30091961220465, 
> 3.30091961220465, 3.03503118006935, 3.03503118006935, 3.03503118006935, 
> 6.9229217846409, 6.9229217846409, 6.9229217846409, 6.84058248620209, 
> 6.84058248620209, 6.84058248620209, 5.95705243892052, 5.95705243892052, 
> 5.95705243892052), V4 = c(0.0510157917418624, 0.0614430466292, 
> 0.15767922584651, 0.0510157917418624, 0.0614430466292, 0.15767922584651, 
> 0.0510157917418624, 0.0614430466292, 0.15767922584651, 0.00450698521094983, 
> 0.0224906710108503, 0.0917704536947984, 0.00450698521094983, 
> 0.0224906710108503, 0.0917704536947984, 0.00450698521094983, 
> 0.0224906710108503, 0.0917704536947984)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
> "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

---

Thank you all 
Cheers

Comment: Please paste the output of `dput(both_long)` into your question to make your data easily accessible.

Comment: Your current output picture helps, but I meant type `dput(both_long)` into R and paste the result onto your question.  This produces a copy of your data that is in the correct format for us to use.

Comment: Yeah! I've noticed that. Now the dput is provided =D I've edited the line-breaks to <br/>. If this is not necessary, I can paste the original.

Comment: Hm. Your data has triplicated logFPKM values with different se's. Thus you have per gene and sample three values which are plotted. This is what you see in your plot. The code looks fine, so.

Comment: Damn... I've screwed everything during the melt. And didn't even noticed because the original table is way longer. Now with just the head, it is easier to see.

Comment: Thank you, guys. And sorry ;-(

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, in your data you have three identical `logFPKM` values per sample and gene with different se's. Thus, you can try to plot each value independently using an interaction for instance:

```
library(tidyverse)
both_long %>% 
  group_by(gene_id, sample) %>% 
  mutate(sample2=interaction(1:n(),sample)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=sample2,y=logFPKM,fill=factor(gene_id), ymax=logFPKM+se, ymin=logFPKM-se)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Jimbou. I really messed up my stuff during the wide-to-long convertion, and I must go two steps back to solve the real problem. You guys helped a lot in this issue, and I definitely have A LOT to learn in R.